# Software channels, what are they?

Tags: fmod, channel

Learning how to use `FMOD` and using this guide:

```
http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/a-quick-guide-to-fmod-r2098
```

It says under the Initialization sub-title that the second parameter in `FSOUND_Init` is the maximum amount of software channels. Could someone please explain or provide a link to an article which explains `what software channels are`. 
If possible please keep the explanations as simple as possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can learn a lot from FMOD samples. u should have a look on them.
Channel can manipulate with your sound (e.g. You can set sound volume via Channels)
Maximum amout of channels mean how many sounds you can play simultaneously.